# Android device crash without error messages

Tags: android, android-ndk, crash

I am writing an android application which makes use of ndk.

After some time that my app is running the device crashes and restarts into recovery mode.

Anyone know of a way to debug this?

There are no outputs in logcat or kmsg regarding this crash.

Comment: If the device is rebooting, `/proc/last_kmsg` should have the cause.  (It's included automatically in the bugreport output you can trigger from the developer menu after a reboot.)  Odd that it would restart in *recovery* mode.

Comment: sadly, there is no /proc/last_kmsg.

Comment: It varies on some devices.  Generate a bugreport after the reboot and search for "LAST KMSG".  (`adb bugreport > bug.txt` as root, or select it from the developer options menu)

Comment: thanks, but it is not creating the log.